# Error while trying to install vagrant-aws plugin

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, vagrant, bundler

I'm trying to add the vagrant-aws plugin to my installation of Vagrant. Upon running this command:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

I get this error message:

```
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    "c:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `x86'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_generator'"  > generator-i386-mingw32.def'
make: *** [generator-i386-mingw32.def] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Steve/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Steve/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

At first I thought I would need to manually install Ruby and Gem in order to fix this, but then I realized that Vagrant's Bundler system should automatically take care of all this. I'm at a loss and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh.. Windows and Linux build/make tools will never get along.

As you can see from the error: ``` /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token ``x86' ```  - The problem is with the parentheses characters in the path.

I think newer Vagrant version [solved](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1571) these problems by installing Vagrant in Program Data directories.

Comment: I'm on version 1.7.1. The latest is 1.7.2. Do you think upgrading will make a difference?

Comment: Oh, probably not. What will help is to re-install Vagrant in path without parentheses in it. I think the default path for Vagrant is `C:\HashiCoprt\Vagrant` now days, not sure how it got installed in `Program Files(x86)` in your case.

Comment: When I uninstalled, it actually was in C:\HashiCoprt\Vagrant. There must have been some other component in Program Files (x86). I reinstalled in C:\Program Files (both of these directories exist by default on Windows 7 running on 64 bit machines). I still get the same error in Vagrant.

Comment: Is this path is in you %PATH% variable?

Comment: I don't know why, but even though I specified "Program Files", my reinstallation once again put it into "Program Files (x86)". So I reinstalled again and this time used the default directory again (Hashicorp/Vagrant). I added "C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin" to my %PATH% variable and restarted. Now when I run the original command, the error is different:

"Could not find gem 'aws-vagrant (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine."

FYI, my %PATH% variable also includes these: C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\rubygems\bin;

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, I stayed up for awhile fighting with this issue. I had just switched over to Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca from being a long time windows user.

Vagrant version 1.7.2, pretty fresh install of Mint 17.1

Kept getting that same error when trying to install various plugins for vagrant, mainly hostsupdater but I bet this fixes all the issues as it is the same error. I read tons of threads and answers and this is what ended up working.

## 1: Followed this guide and installed Ruby 2.2.0

http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you

Note: Make sure you visit the sites where he links off to the README for installing ruby, his copy paste for code is messed up.

## 2: You were expecting more, nope!

Installing all plugins just worked perfect after that, did need to use sudo though but other than that.

Hope this saves someone a ton of time looking...